# How can I add the time onto a Date string?

Tags: vb.net

I am looking to add `12:00:00 AM` onto both of the dates.

```
Public Shared Function AddSkill(ByVal empId As Integer, ByVal skillCode As String, ByVal startDate As String, ByVal endDate As String) As String

    Dim sDate As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(startDate)
    Dim eDate As DateTime = DateTime.Parse(endDate)

    Dim empSkill As EmployeeSkills
    empSkill = Nothing

    If empId > 0 Then
        empSkill = EmployeeSkills.GetById(empId)
    End If

    If empSkill Is Nothing Then
        empSkill = New EmployeeSkills
    End If

    empSkill.SkillID = skillCode
    empSkill.EmployeeID = empId
    empSkill.StartTime = sDate & sDate.Hour & sDate.Minute & sDate.Second
    empSkill.Endtime = eDate & eDate.Hour & eDate.Minute & eDate.Second
    empSkill.Save(FSIASecurity.GetUserID)

    Return New JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(empSkill)

End Function
```

startDate is `25/05/2015`
endDate can be anything but we'll say `31/05/2016` for demo purposes.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Time portion is already part of `DateTime`.

Comment: But when I try to change a date to one of these dates the time is not there?

Comment: Can you post more code and how you look for the time portion. As it stands, I'm not able to make much sense out of your post and comments.

Comment: How do you know it is not there?  How are you showing or examining it?

Comment: I am using the debuggger to examine it

Comment: Your problem does not lie in the reading/parsing portion. It is actually where you try to display it. Look for Format Strings on Google to get more idea about how `DateTime` should be displayed.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(sDate.ToString("G"))` will show you that the time is there, namely `5/31/2015 12:00:00 AM`

Comment: From where are you getting `startdate` and `endate`? If you are fetching these two values from database they why don't you do the formatting in DB itself?

Answer (score 2):

You should try something like this:

```
'The following example uses the DateTime constructor to instantiate a DateTime value.
Dim date1 As New Date(2015, 5, 25, 12, 0, 0)
```

Learn more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/272ba130(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: remember you should put more effort in your awnser, because it can become useless or at least just too much specific in the case of the link you posted becomes dead.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your current culture has the date format "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss AM/PM", like in Canada.

If you use `Dim sDate = DateTime.Parse("25/05/2015")` then the time portion of it is set to 00:00:00 in the morning. That is already 12 AM. You can check this if you use `sDate.ToString()`, you will get `"25/05/2015 12:00:00 AM"` from it.

If you want to have another time of day, just add the amount of time since midnight to `sDate`:

For 1:00 PM this is `Dim sDate = DateTime.Parse("25/05/2015") + new TimeSpan(13,0,0)`.